# Difference B/W return json and javascriptserialer

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

can somebody please tell me the difference if i do in my ActionResult

in this case

```
var transAcc= "SomeListHere";
var  v = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(transAcc);
return Content(v);
```

and

```
var transAcc= "SameListHere";
return Json(new {list=transAcc });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that in the first case you are not setting the Content-Type response header to `application/json` while in the second this is done.

In first case the response is plain text and looks like this:

```
"SomeListHere"
```

And the `Content-Type` header is set to `text/html` which is incorrect as this is not HTML. It's `text/plain`. That's not even a valid JSON string.

In the second case it is a JSON string which looks like this:

```
{"list":"SomeListHere"}
```

Also in the first code example you are manually performing the JSON serialization which is plumbing code and should not be done in a controller and should be externalized in a custom ActionResult which is exactly what the creators of the ASP.NET MVC framework have don for you in the face of JsonResult which is your second code example.

Conclusion: if you want to send a JSON serialized representation of some model to the client always use the second approach.

Comment: "SomeListHere" is a `SelectListItem` i just added the `"someListHere"` for simplification .... is it still the same

Comment: @john, well a SelectListItem serializes differently in JSON but there still will be the difference as in the second example you are using the `list` property. You should use the second example as it sets proper Content-Type header.

Answer (score 1):

None. Second one uses the first one. But I find the second **more readable**.

Here is the code behind `JsonResult`'s `ExecuteResult` (using reflector) which is used in your second case:

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
    .... // some stuff
    if (this.Data != null)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        response.Write(serializer.Serialize(this.Data));
    }
}
```

## UPDATE

Darin's response is correct although mine showing internals of the second.